# Variation of Parameters solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system which I am attempting to solve via variation of parameters but I keep getting imaginary answers. According to the example problem I was given imaginary answers can be written more conventionally in the form of sine and cosine but I am totally unsure how to deal with this.

$X'= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
6 & -1\\
4 & 6\\
\end{array} \right)X+\left( \begin{array}{cc}
sin(2t) \\
2cos(2t)
\end{array} \right)e^{6t}$

Anything helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solving of homogeneous equation:

Eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $\begin{pmatrix}
6&-1\\ 
4&6  
\end{pmatrix}$ are
$$\lambda_1=6+2i,v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
i\\ 
2  
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\lambda_2=6-2i,v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
i\\ 
-2  
\end{pmatrix}.$$
$$\therefore 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2  
\end{pmatrix}
=C_1e^{(6+2i)t}\begin{pmatrix}
i\\ 
2  
\end{pmatrix}+C_2e^{(6-2i)t}\begin{pmatrix}
i\\ 
-2  
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\Longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2  
\end{pmatrix}
=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}i\left(C_1e^{(2t)i}+C_2e^{-(2t)i}\right)\\2\left(C_1e^{(2t)i}-C_2e^{-(2t)i}\right)\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\Longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2  
\end{pmatrix}
=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}i\left[C_1\left(\cos{2t}+i\sin{2t}\right)+C_2\left(\cos{2t}-i\sin{2t}\right)\right]\\2\left[C_1\left(\cos{2t}+i\sin{2t}\right)-C_2\left(\cos{2t}-i\sin{2t}\right)\right]\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\Longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2  
\end{pmatrix}
=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}i\left[\left(C_1+C_2\right)\cos{2t}+i\left(C_1-C_2\right)\sin{2t}\right]\\2\left[\left(C_1-C_2\right)\cos{2t}+i\left(C_1+C_2\right)\sin{2t}\right]\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\Longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2  
\end{pmatrix}
=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}C_1'\cos{2t}-C_2'\sin{2t}\\2\left[C_1'\sin{2t}+C_2'\cos{2t}\right]\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\Longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2  
\end{pmatrix}
=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{2t}&-\sin{2t}\\2\sin{2t}&2\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
C_1'\\ 
C_2'  
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $C_1'=i\left(C_1+C_2\right) 
$ and $ C_2'=C_1-C_2$.

So,
$$X_c=PC'$$
where
$P=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{2t}&-\sin{2t}\\2\sin{2t}&2\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix}$ and $C'=\begin{pmatrix}
C_1'\\ 
C_2'  
\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, 
$$X_p=P\int P^{-1} f(t) dt$$
$$\Longrightarrow X_p=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{2t}&-\sin{2t}\\2\sin{2t}&2\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix}\int e^{-6t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{2t}&-\sin{2t}\\2\sin{2t}&2\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
\sin{2t}\\ 
2\cos{2t}  
\end{pmatrix}e^{6t} dt$$

$$\Longrightarrow X_p=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{2t}&-\sin{2t}\\2\sin{2t}&2\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix}\int \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}2\cos{2t}&\sin{2t}\\-2\sin{2t}&\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\sin{2t}\\ 
2\cos{2t}  
\end{pmatrix} dt$$

$$\Longrightarrow X_p=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{2t}&-\sin{2t}\\2\sin{2t}&2\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix}\int \begin{pmatrix}
\sin{4t}\\ 
\cos{4t}  
\end{pmatrix} dt$$

$$\Longrightarrow X_p=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{2t}&-\sin{2t}\\2\sin{2t}&2\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{4} \begin{pmatrix}
-\cos{4t}\\ 
\sin{4t}  
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\Longrightarrow X_p=\frac{e^{6t}}{4} \begin{pmatrix}
-\cos{4t}\\ 
2\sin{4t}  
\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore,

$$X=X_c+X_p$$
$$\Longrightarrow X=e^{6t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos{2t}&-\sin{2t}\\2\sin{2t}&2\cos{2t}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
C_1'\\ 
C_2'  
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{e^{6t}}{4} \begin{pmatrix}
-\cos{4t}\\ 
2\sin{4t}  
\end{pmatrix}$$